# スクレイピングにおけるエラー（TypeError: 'str' object is not callable）が生じましたが具体的な対策がわかりません

Tags: python, web-scraping

#### 前提・実現したいこと

pythonでseleniumを用いて，abemaの番組タイトルの取得を行おうとコードを組んでいたところ，TypeError: 'str' object is not callableといったエラーが生じてしまいました。

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

#### 該当のソースコード

エラーが出た箇所は次の箇所です

```py
#タイトル
  title=item.find_elements_by_xpath("div[1]/div/p/span/div/span")
  if len(title):
    print(str(cnt)+":"+title[0].text())
```

全体のコードは次のようになります

```
from typing import Container
import urllib.request
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep, time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')


driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/ユーザー名/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)

driver.get('https://abema.tv/timetable')
sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'19歳以下')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'男性')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'次へ')]").click()
sleep(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("com-genre-survey-GenreSurveyCard__text").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(text(),'完了')]").click()
sleep(10)
category=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='com-timetable-ChannelIconHeader__channel-link com-a-Link com-a-Link--dim']")
img=category.find_elements_by_xpath("picture/img")
if len(img):
  src=img[0].get_attribute('src')
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(src,"img.png")
category.click()
sleep(10)
timetable=driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='com-timetable-TimetableItem__wrapper']")
cnt=0
for item in timetable:
  cnt+=1
  #タイトル
  title=item.find_elements_by_xpath("div[1]/div/p/span/div/span")[0].get_attribute("innerHTML").text()
  if len(title):
    print(str(cnt)+":"+title)
```

#### 試したこと

次のサイト(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488606/typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-using-selenium-through-python)を参考にし

```
title=item.find_elements_by_xpath("div[1]/div/p/span/div/span")[0].text
print(str(cnt)+":"+title)
```

```
 title=item.find_elements_by_xpath("div[1]/div/p/span/div/span")[0].get_attribute("innerHTML").text()
  print(str(cnt)+":"+title)
```

等を行っても同じエラーが生じました

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

Python 3.9.5
selenium 3.141.0
ChromeDriver 92.0.4515.107

Comment: 問題の本質がどこで何であるかは別として、エラーメッセージからすると既に文字列になっているようなので、試しにその行の`.text`や`.text()`を削除してみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: text()でなくtextとした結果解決しました。コピペのミスがあり，その点がエラーにつながっていたようです。ご対応いただきありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

text()でなくtextとした結果解決しました。
詳細は次のサイトを参照ください(https://teratail.com/questions/352245#reply-482192)

Answer (score 1):

まず、Pythonではすべてがオブジェクトであることを覚えておいてください。関数もまた、これらのオブジェクトには特殊性があり、それは「呼び出し可能」オブジェクトです。例えば `func()` の関数を呼び出すと、関数定義に移動して、その関数定義のメソッド `__call()__` を実行します。エラー `'str' object is not callable` は、そのメソッドを持たない string のメソッド `__call()__` を呼び出そうとしていることを意味します。

Comment: エラー 'str' object is not callable は、stringに__call()__がないのに__call()__を実行したためにこのようなエラーが生じたという認識でよろしいでしょうか。

Comment: いいえ、そのメソッドは存在しないためです

Comment: 了解しました。ありがとうございます。